# Selenium ChromeDriver load extension problem with path

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to load an extension into ChromeDriver like this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--load-extension=file:/path/extension");

driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

But I get an error:

> Failed to load extension from:
>
> C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\69...\file:\path\extension.
>
> Manifest file is missing or unreadable

How to make ChromeDriver to load extension exactly from where I tell him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following, from [this site](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/extensions):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: It works if use `.crx`. I have a folder. P.S.: `ChromeDriver(capabilities)` is deprecated, you can use directly `ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions)`.